# "torch" and "pytorch" version mismatch in conda

Tags: python, pytorch, conda, torch

I installed the following in an environment:

```
cudatoolkit=11.3
pytorch=1.11.0
torchvision=0.12.0
```

But when asking for the torch/cuda version I get this:

```
$ python3 -c "import torch; print(torch.__version__)"
1.12.1+cu102
```

Which is not what I want (1.12.1 would be fine, but cu102 is too old). Looking further, I see this:

```
$ conda list torch
# packages in environment at /home/ml/anaconda3/envs/ldm:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pytorch                   1.11.0          py3.8_cuda11.3_cudnn8.2.0_0    pytorch
pytorch-lightning         1.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pytorch-mutex             1.0                        cuda    pytorch
torch                     1.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
torch-fidelity            0.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
torchdiffeq               0.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
torchmetrics              0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
torchvision               0.12.0               py38_cu113    pytorchcode
```

So "pytorch" has the version I want (with cuda11.3), but "torch" is 1.12.1. Why? Moreover, "torch" does not seem to be a conda package (PackagesNotFoundError when trying to install), which is surprising since it appears in "conda list".

There is clearly something I do not understand about conda / pytorch. Can someone please explain it?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, the `torch` package uses the LuaRocks Package manager. And if you use it mostly in python, you should aim for 'PyTorch', which conda only takes care of.

For your case, I strongly suggest you create a new environment and start again installing PyTorch and it's components from the beginning. Read this [compatibility matrix](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/wiki/PyTorch-Versions) and try to install it according to those tables.

Comment: I simply did ```conda env create -f``` with the environment.yaml file from stable diffusion (https://github.com/invoke-ai/InvokeAI/blob/main/environment.yaml), so I don't expect the choice of versions to be a problem. Indeed the compatibility matrix that you linked includes pytorch 1.11 and torchvision 0.12 on the same line.

As I said, my question is to understand why torch.__version__ is the same as that weird "torch" package and not the "pytorch" one.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end that "torch" fake (?) package was my previous install of pytorch and cuda (with pip). The conda install actually made the pip one not work anymore ("import torch" was not working outside of the environment). Which is even weirder since my understanding of virtual environment was that it should at the very least not affect what's outside.

The solution was to reinstall pytorch with pip (outside the environment). After that, "import torch" worked inside the environment. Which again is weird since conda installed his own version of pytorch, apparently not to use it in the end.

I consider this an "answer" as it solves the problem I was having, but I still don't understand why conda behaved this way.